# Getting WordPress permalinks working on a MAMP install

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, mamp, permalinks

I've got a local MAMP install of WordPress and am trying to get permalinks working.  But when I click my links after setting permalink setting to 'Day and name' `http://localhost/wordpress_1/2011/01/12/sample-post/`

I get 404ed

> Not Found: The requested URL
>   /wordpress_1/2011/01/05/hello-world/
>   was not found on this server.

Is this a mod_rewrite issue? mod_rewrite is listed in the 'loaded modules' section of my phpinfo.  Do I need to do something else to enable it?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

From my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Changed my httpd.conf from

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And it works.

Answer (score 3):

Follow symlinks needs to be turned on in MAMP.

Open your httpd.conf file in /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/
Look for `<Directory />`
Make sure that you have the following Options set:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

You can also setup a local virtual host for better testing of your WordPress site. It's beyond the scope of this question/topic, but if you'd like I can create an example config file and instructions on how to do that.

Comment: The Options directive was already set, it was the AllowOverride I needed to change... See my answer for details

Comment: @Yarin - Ah, glad you got it working. BTW, here are instructions for using virtual hosts on MAMP if you don't have MAMP Pro: http://pastebin.com/ygFMejdF